# Calculating pressure in water

Tags: physics, solution-verification, fluid-dynamics

> I am trying to determine the horizontal pressure gradient in a scenario where water is drained out from the bottom of a tub. The height of the water surface varies by $0.01$m over horizontal distance of $0.10$m and water speeds in the tub are $0.3$m/s.

From the equation $$\text{pressure}=\text{force}/\text{area}\implies \text{pressure}=\rho g h.$$ Here, $\rho$ is the density of water, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity at the surface and $h$ is the height of the liquid column/depth in the substance.

Thus, \begin{align}
\text{pressure}&=997 \ \text{kg/m$^3$}\cdot 9.81\ \text{m/s$^2$}\cdot 0.01 \ \text{m} \\
&=97.8057 \ \text{Pa}.
\end{align}
Dividing this by $0.1$m gives $978.057$ Pa/m. Is this solution valid?

Comment: would your answer have been any different if the water speeds were double that given